# WSUS: determine if there are still updates pending on a server?

Tags: windows, update, wsus

I was wondering if there's a way to monitor how much updates there are still pending on a server?

Let me give some background; we have 2 application servers. One of them is the database server and one of them is the application server. Both of them are patched using wsus on the same time but the application server can't start if the database server is still running updates and therefore may reboot.

I can script the shutdown and power on of the application server but I need to know when there are no more updates pending on the database server and therefore not reboot anymore?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

This more of a server side question, rather than WSUS one.

Here is a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968999/how-to-test-if-windows-server-is-fully-updated-trying-to-create-an-update-rebo) for the same thing.

And here is a post of the Hey Scripting Guy blog, tackling your specific issue - [Part 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/10/determine-pending-reboot-status-powershell-style-part-1.aspx) and [Part 2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/11/determine-pending-reboot-status-powershell-style-part-2.aspx)

Basically check if `[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired]` exist.